# confusion about ruby CONSTANT

Tags: ruby, constants

Suppose a simple ruby program about CONSTANT variable:

```
OUTER_CONST = 99
class Const
  def get_const
    CONST
  end
  CONST = OUTER_CONST + 1
end

puts Const.new.get_const
```

I assume the result of `Const.new.get_const` should be nil, but the result is 100! I wonder why?

Comment: Why vote me down! Please stand out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Ruby is [dynamic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language) and the constant lookup happens at runtime. Also keep in mind that your script is evaluated sequentially (ie. line by line).

I've added some comments for clarity:

```
OUTER_CONST = 99

class Const
  def get_const
    CONST
  end

  CONST = OUTER_CONST + 1
  # the CONST constant is now
  # defined and has the value 100
end

# at this point the Const class
# and CONST constant are defined and can be used

# here you are calling the `get_const` method
# which asks for the value of `CONST` so the 
# constant lookup procedure will now start and
# will correctly pick up the current value of `CONST`
Const.new.get_const # => 100
```

Answer (score 4):

`get_const` is a method, and you are calling it *after* `CONST` definition; so when you call it `CONST` is already defined.

`def get_const ... end` defines a method, **does not execute its content**; you execute its content when you call it at the `Const.new.get_const` line, so when `CONST` is already defined.

**Besides**: if `CONST` was not defined at the moment of `get_const` call, you would not get `nil`, but a `NameError`:

```
class Const
  def get_const
    CONST
  end
end

Const.new.get_const #=> NameError: uninitialized constant Const::CONST
```

Comment: I guess when Class `Const` is initialized,  `CONST = OUTER_CONST + 1` has not been executed. So, I wonder how can ruby recognize `CONST` definition? That's my question.

Comment: @user2886717 sure, but note that `def get_const ... end` defines a method, **does not execute its content**; you execute its content when you call it (at the `Const.new.get_const` line), so when `CONST` is already defined